# Azure Mobile App on Service Fabric

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-mobile-services, azure-service-fabric, offlineapps

I am using the Offline Sync feature of Azure Mobile Apps and it is working as expected.

I am also running a Service Fabric cluster on Azure for other services.

Is there anything that would prevent me technically or legally from running the Azure Mobile App on Service Fabric? (As opposed to running Azure Moble App on Azure Mobile App host on Azure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps uses three things:

1. Offline sync with a SQL Azure instance backend - fully supported on whatever container you choose
2. Push Registrations connected via App Service Push - will not be supported outside of Azure App Service
3. Authentication via server-flow or client-flow - will not be supported outside of Azure App Service

You don't have a problem legally - Azure Mobile Apps is an open-source project licensed under a OSS friendly license.  However, Auth and Push are going to be issues if you use them.